# How to remove FrameLayout tag during View Recycle RecylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `FrameLayout` in `RecyclerView` item. Within which I have a button which does the upload/download action. In `onBindViewHolder`, I assign unique id to `FrameLayout` tag and in `onViewRecycled()`, I reassign the `FrameLayout`'s tag to null. So each row in the `RecyclerView`, the frame layout tag should contain unique tag value.

When the user clicks upload or download button, the corresponding action should be performed and the respective button should disappear after the operation completes.

So when the operation completes, I find view by using `findViewbyTag(pass the unique identifier)`, it works fine, the respective buttons (buttons are within `FrameLayout`. I am changing `FrameLayout` alpha to make it disappear). But it disappears for some of the other recycler view items also.

Below is the code I put in for the `FrameLayout`. `SessionId` is unique for each row

```
holder.uploadDownloadContainer.tag = sessionId
```

`onViewRecycled()` has below code,

```
holder.uploadDownloadContainer.tag = null
```

once the download completes,

```
val containerView = view?.findViewWithTag(downloadData.sessionId) as? FrameLayout

containerView?.let {
            onUiThread {
                info("Fading away upload/download button")
                containerView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(500).start()
            }
        }
```

Can someone point whats going wrong here, why other row's upload/download button (`FrameLayout`) is also deleting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a list of model class items in order to store the details of the items. And do the required view changes in the on bind view of the adapter. This will help to maintain the States correctly. Instead of assigning the values with respect to the tag ID. When you need to update the item state call the recycler view adapter notify methods, which will invoke the on bind for the item.